# Mod Rewrite rule to Zeus Server rule (Codeigniter)

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, codeigniter, url-rewriting, zeus

I'm about to go live with a Codeigniter powered site. I want to remove index.php from the url so that instead of this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php/controller
```

I get something like this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/controller
```

So far, pretty straightforward. In the past I've used the mod-rewrite rule supplied by the Codeigniter documentation:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This works like a charm. However, for this site, I'm having to use a Zeus web server rather than Apache, and I'm not familiar with it at all. Zeus has its own rewrite rules such that this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f  
RewriteRule ^[^/]*\.html$ index.php
```

would become this:

```
match URL into $ with ^/[^/]*\.html$
if matched then set URL = /index.php
```

Can anyone help me rewrite the first rule for Zeus? Any help very gratefully received!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out - the following works nicely for me:

```
map path into SCRATCH:DOCROOT from /

set SCRATCH:ORIG_URL = %{URL}
set SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI = %{URL}

look for file at %{SCRATCH:DOCROOT}%{SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI}
if not exists then look for dir at %{SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI}%{SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI}
if not exists then set URL = /index.php%{SCRATCH:REQUEST_URI}
```