# Apache mod rewrite rules to Zeus rewrite rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, zeus

This morning I wanted to move my development website online (in a protected folder), but I figured out that our host (on a shared server) does not use apache mod_rewrite but Zeus rules. I've never heard about that before but it seems that apache rules could be automatically converted via a command line, but as you can guess I have no such access on the server.
So, do you know any online coverter from Apache rules to Zeus ones? (I tried google but found nothing).

Or could someone translate these simple rules with his server:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

It should normaly be something like:

```
match URL into $ with ^[^\/]*\.html$
if matched then
   set URL = index.php
endif
```

But it just doesn't do anything, just the annoying 404 error page.

Cheers,
Nicolas.

Comment: I've just noticed that my question is close to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972666/apache-mod-rewrite-rules-to-zeus-rewrite-rules .It seems he didn't get any answer...

Comment: seen this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338511/mod-rewrite-rule-to-zeus-server-rule-codeigniter

Comment: @josek: Yes I saw this one, but the first example is exactly the same as mine, and the second one shouldn't be an answer of his specific configuration?

Comment: one question (but i dont know too much on this) - your Apache rule does not send ^[^\/]*\.html$ but . to index.php. So should the Zeus rule be match URL into $ with (.*)

Comment: @josek: You mean that: "match URL into $ with .*$" ? It's still not working but I think we're closer to the solution

Comment: http://www.names.co.uk/knowledge/scripting/rewrite_scripts/528-zeus_rewrite_rules_user_guide.html has your specific example. See section "Wordpress"

Comment: yeah excatly what I was about to tell you, but unfortunatelly I have a 403 error now. Maybe the rewriting does not work if the website is in a subfolder? I tried to add /subfolder/ as a prefix, but still struggling. Thanks for your response anyway :)

Comment: To be precise, I have a 403 error when I add a "/" (slash) at the end of an URL and a 404 without. I think without it thinks it's a file? That's really annoying, wasting that much of time because the host doesn't use mod_rewrite from Apache...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the problem.
First I fixed my rules issues with [this ressource](http://www.names.co.uk/knowledge/scripting/rewrite_scripts/528-zeus_rewrite_rules_user_guide.html), but that wasn't working at all, so I decided to **put the script.rewrite file in the WEBROOT folder** of my website... and then it worked!
I didn't put it in the root at first because the website is located in a subfolder, but it seems that the script.rewrite file isn't detected in this subfolder...

Hope it could help some people around,
Nicolas.